# texi2dvi runs forever if the document contains references not in the .bib file

Tags: biblatex, compiling, texi2dvi

If I run the example below with `texi2dvi (GNU Texinfo 5.2) 5381` [texlive 2012], it never
stops. How can this be avoided? It's somehow strange. I used to have a lot of
references in my files which were not yet in the `.bib` file. It would still
create the `.pdf` and display the keys in bold letters. But in the last couple
of days it seems to have changed (all I did was an upgrade of Ubuntu to
14.04). When I use `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, I get the `.pdf` of course. Please let me know if you need further version numbers etc. (`pdflatex` shows `pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)`)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@article{mykey,
    author={TeX, L.},
    journal={Journal of LaTeX questions},
    pages={1--10},
    title={{Minimal title}},
    volume={1},
    number={1},
    year={2011}}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
Just some reference: \textcite{myfoo}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here is the content of the `.blg` file:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2012)
Capacity: max_strings=35307, hash_size=35307, hash_prime=30011
The top-level auxiliary file: mini.aux
The style file: biblatex.bst
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated wiz_functions (elt_size=4) to 6000 items from 3000.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Database file #1: mini-blx.bib
Database file #2: bib.bib
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "myfoo"
Biblatex version: 2.6
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated wiz_functions (elt_size=4) to 9000 items from 6000.
You've used 1 entry,
            6019 wiz_defined-function locations,
            1124 strings with 8034 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 1306 in all, are:
= -- 64
> -- 58
< -- 1
+ -- 41
- -- 24
* -- 23
:= -- 295
add.period$ -- 0
call.type$ -- 1
change.case$ -- 0
chr.to.int$ -- 34
cite$ -- 0
duplicate$ -- 12
empty$ -- 92
format.name$ -- 0
if$ -- 289
int.to.chr$ -- 0
int.to.str$ -- 0
missing$ -- 0
newline$ -- 22
num.names$ -- 0
pop$ -- 44
preamble$ -- 1
purify$ -- 0
quote$ -- 0
skip$ -- 74
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 117
swap$ -- 1
text.length$ -- 16
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 1
type$ -- 26
warning$ -- 0
while$ -- 50
width$ -- 0
write$ -- 20
(There was 1 warning)
```

Comment: Did you try the  texi2dvi option `--max-iterations=N`?

Comment: Hi Ulrike, thanks for helping and good to hear from you. I just tried it. It stops, but there is still no .pdf generated. This is so strange. That exact process worked for me since roughly 2012... no idea what might have changed.

Comment: Well no that it stopped you can inspect the log-file and blg-file to find out if there are errors somewhere.

Comment: The `.log` contains no errors, just some warnings which I think are non-critical. It has 409 lines (not sure which part would be relevant to post). Can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: The first warning means that your biblatex is too old. It doesn't match the biber version. You need biblatex 2.5 with this biber. (Current is biber 1.8/biblatex 2.8)

Comment: I actually always use `backend=bibtex`, I upated the example accordingly. Still the same problem.

Comment: I am not sure if this has to do with it (http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/universe/proposed/monotone) but I just compiled an old document which always worked. It does not work anymore (runs forever as well, probably also due to a not-found reference). So I assume it's an Ubuntu-thing... not sure what can be done to solve it :-(

Comment: Same problem with `texlive 2013`. `sudo apt-get install texinfo` shows `texinfo is already the newest version`, so `texi2dvi` is already installed in the latest version. Can anybody reproduce this problem?

Comment: No I can't reproduce it: I do have a windows environment and there is not texi2dvi in texlive. The one in miktex is working fine. It sound like a bug to me that texi2dvi doesn't has some internal "max-iteration" number. But I don't understand why you expect a command called texi2**dvi** to create a pdf.

Comment: Use `texi2dvi -p` to create a pdf... but the problem (with or without this option) is that it runs without stopping. `texi2dvi` is widely used (as `latexmk -pdf`, which at least says that `Latex failed to resolve 1 citation(s)` but stops). My minimal example is in one aspect too minimal: if the reference is not printed, nothing is printed and thus no pdf generated anyways (I'll fix that).

Comment: Okay,... it thus really seems to be a `texi2dvi` problem.

Comment: I also tried it with the very latest version of texi2dvi from http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/texinfo/latest/texi2dvi and then decided to file a bug report.

Comment: I just obtained an answer from Karl Berry (texinfo). It is an issue with biblatex. They are working on it. For now, setting `--max-iterations` at least avoids the loop.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug in the software (see comment above).