# latexmk vs texi2dvi?

Tags: latexmk, texi2dvi

I am wondering what the differences between `latexmk` and `texi2dvi` are. To my surprise I haven't found this here nor via google (apart from a post back in 2004 which I am not sure how accurate it is). I use both of these tools every once in a while but don't see any advantages of one over the other for my purposes. Are both maintained actively, can both do the same tasks, what about performance...? Would be nice to have at least some of the major aspects summarized for future reference.

Answer (score 3):

fundamentally, `latexmk` and `texi2dvi` do the same job: compile a document “enough” times that all references are resolved.

thus they're both useful for many applications.  personally, i would tend toward using `texi2dvi` for `texinfo`-formatted documents, and `latexmk` for latex-formatted documents, but...

that said, users should note that the [the ctan topics page](http://www.ctan.org/topic/compilation) lists 26 different things to do this sort of job, and i (and many others, i don't doubt) have ‘personally configured’ scripts of various sorts to do the job.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I am aware of these 'basic facts', alternatives or pages like http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=make. My hope was to hear more about the technical differences. I'll give it more time so that more people can respond.

Comment: Just to mention some points: If there is an error in the document and `texi2dvi` fails (leaving a folder `.t2d`), then compilation with `texi2dvi` after fixing the error still fails. One first has to remove the `.t2d` folder and then it would work. This is not necessary with `latexmk`. Also, `latexmk` does not face the problem of running forever (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173077/texi2dvi-runs-forever-if-the-document-contains-references-not-in-the-bib-file): On the other hand, `latexmk` is significantly slower than `texi2dvi` (in an example document: 17s vs 10s).